# Using MIN with multiple MATCH criteria (Track and Field Stats)

Tags: microsoft-excel

As a track coach, I want to keep a running spread sheet of the athletes' best performances over various events in Excel. I'll then use conditional formatting to highlight athletes that qualify for post-season meets based on their running season bests.

The overall stats ("Season Stats Summary") sheet I have looks like this, with athlete names in column A, events in columns B through (whatever), and then the athlete's best (MIN) time they've achieved to date in the season (leaving cells blank if there's no mark recorded yet).

[image: Season Stats Summary]

As we complete meets,
I can dump meet results into a separate raw data sheet such as this:
[image: Raw Stats]

I'd like to use a formula in the overall Season Stats sheet that matches athletes to events and finds the best (minimum) time they've run for that event.  I can take it from there with the conditional formatting, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the best score given the two matching criteria and allowing for duplicate name/event matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2019 or Office 365, you can use the `MINIFS` function to get the minimum value that satisfies multiple criteria.

Assuming that the raw data in your question is in columns A:E of "Sheet1", and your Season Stats Summary is in columns A:H of another sheet, put the following formula in cell B2 of the "Season Stats Summary" sheet and copy it to the remaining cells.

```
=MINIFS(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5,$A2,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5,B$1)
```

This finds the lowest value in column E (mark) of the raw data where the athlete name (column D in raw data) equals this athlete's name and the event (column C in raw data) is the event listed in this column's header.

Note that the best time will be listed as zero for events that the athlete never competed in. You can set the number format of the cells to display zero as blank, or if you need the value of the cell to be blank, change the formula to:

```
=IF(MINIFS(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5,$A2,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5,B$1)=0,"",MINIFS(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5,$A2,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5,B$1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what I needed.  (I up-voted but I'm new so it may not count).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it Works:**

- Sample Data Range is **A17:G24**, including *Headers*.
- Write this Array Formula in Cell **B28**, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill *Right* then *Down*.

  ```
  {=MIN(IF($A$19:$A$24=$A28,C$19:C$24))}
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*